# How to set MSB of a UShort Variable?

Tags: c#

i'm having a UShort variable `Temp` and which has a value `1`.

How to set the most-significant bit of this value as 1.

Answer (score 6):

You use `or` to overwrite the "leftmost" bit:

```
ushort temp=1;
temp |= 1<<15;
```

Where `15` is the number of bits in your data type (16) minus 1 because your `1` is already in position 1.

Answer (score 0):

Or...since you know the size of your data type:

```
public ushort setHighOrderBit( ushort foo )
{
  return foo |= 0x8000 ;
}
```

[my bad. Not enough coffee this AM]

Comment: No, an unsigned constant will be zero-padded on the left, and a signed constant will be sign extended.  In no case would right-padding occur.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ushort value = 307;
byte lsb = (byte)(value & 0xFFu);
byte msb = (byte)((value >> 8) & 0xFFu);
```